# Reactivo Programming Exercise

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I have an source observable that emits when you click. I want to make an operator that emits like the next marble diagram  ...

That is, it emits when making the first click. Then, it emits when you have 2 items, then it emits when you have 3 items, etc.

[image: Marble diagram]

I know that can be done with scan and filter operators, but my question is, if it is possible to do it with the bufferWhen operator?.

I tried to do it (like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-i5hic2?devtoolsheight=60)), but the result is not what I expected (the first click is not emitted immediately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as follow code. Try avoid reusing source in `bufferWhen`, there may be race condition

```
const source$ = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  map(_ => new Date())
);

interval(1000).pipe(
  tap(d => console.log('CLICK:', d)),
  bufferWhen(() => {
    return source$
  })
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: The problem is that the source observable is the click events too. So, it's not possible to do it with the bufferWhen operator because the race condition

Comment: it probably makes more sense to use a combination of reduce() and repeat(). bufferWhen its normally should control by third party observable

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using bufferWhen:

```js
const obs$ = defer(() => {
    let amountToTake = 1;

    const clicks$ = fromEvent(this.btnStart.nativeElement, 'click');
    const counter$ = clicks$.pipe(scan(acc => acc + 1, 0));
    const counterConnectable$ = counter$.pipe(shareReplay(1));

    return counterConnectable$.pipe(
        exhaustMap(_ => 
            counterConnectable$.pipe(take(amountToTake), bufferCount(amountToTake))
        ),
        tap(() => amountToTake++),
    );
})

obs$.subscribe(console.log);
```